# How do you write multiple files consecutively in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I have the following section of code

```
fileHelper.writeFile(firstPage, Constants.METAMORPH_ENG_TXT);
ArrayList<String> list = textTokenizer.tokenize(firstPage, Locale.US);
list = textTokenizer.replaceNewLines(list);
fileHelper.writeFile(list, Constants.METAMORPH_ENG_TXT_FMT);
```

With this as my writeFile method

```
public void writeFile(ArrayList<String> linesToWrite, String nameOfFile)
{
    BufferedWriter bw = SingletonBufferedWritter.getBufferedWritter(nameOfFile);

    for(String s: linesToWrite)
    {
        try
        {
            bw.write(s);
            bw.newLine();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try
    {
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this as my SingletonBufferedWritter

```
public class SingletonBufferedWritter 
{

    private static BufferedWritter bw = null;

    public static BufferedWritter getBufferedWritter(String nameOfFile)
    {
        if(bw == null)
        {
            try
            {
                bw = new BufferedWritter(new FileReader(nameOfFile));
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return bw;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to write two files consecutively, but my code stops working after I've only written one file. I've checked and my code does indeed write the first file but it fails to write the second. I have no idea why. How can I fix this so that I can write both files?

Comment: I suggest that you use a debugger to trace through your code and find out what it is doing.

Comment: Erm, well, you have a badly implemented Singleton that means you have exactly one `BufferedWriter` ... pointed at one file.

Comment: @BrianRoach How should I implement my singleton? Do I need to make my application multithreaded? I've never worked with multiple threads before. Can you point me in the direction of something I can read?

Comment: Why are you using a Singleton at all? You close the BufferedWriter after the first method call, so it can't be used again.

Comment: sorry, I misread "consecutively" as "concurrently".

Comment: You may need to consider a `Factory Pattern` instead of `Singleton` or try to have two `bw` one for each file.

Comment: @user2282497 I just read about the design pattern and I wanted to implement it.

Comment: @Rp- My problem had more to do with the fact that I was using a Singleton as opposed to me using a buffered writer incorrectly. I ended up writing a factory to my my writers and readers. If you make your comment an answer then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to consider a `Factory Pattern` for each type of writer instead of `Singleton` or try to have two `bw` one for each file.

Answer (score 0):

Once you close your "singleton" `BufferedWritter`, you never open another one. In short, you never open more than one file to write.

To be clear, every call after the first to `getBufferedWritter` ignores its argument and returns the `BufferedWritter` used to write the first file and which has since been closed -- assuming `br` and `bw` are the same variable and one of the two is not declared in a scope not shown in your question...

Comment: Did I implement the singleton incorrectly? Also, there is no "open" for Java's buffered writer class but I can't write the file unless I close the buffered writer. Should I not be using a singleton? Someone else suggested a factory pattern.

Comment: A singleton doesn't really make sense, since you're trying to use it for different files (which need different writers). There is no open, correct - you have to create a new writer when you close the old one.

Comment: Without a method to reuse a `BufferedWriter`, there is no point in trying to allocate only one in using the singleton pattern. There really is no need to use a factory pattern either. Just create a new `BufferedWriter` for each file if that is what the `BufferedWriter` requires.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in your singleton, your variable is bw everywhere(not sure what is br), when you write you seconde file, you Bufferwritter will not be recreated with METAMORPH_ENG_TXT_FMT.

So it gets flushed and closed, hence your next iteration won't work